# Using different range to sort numerous columns with different row lengths

Tags: loops, sorting, while-loop

I am using this snippet from recorder.

```
Columns("O:O").Select  
Dim SortO As Long
   SortO = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("O2:O" & SortO) _
       , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Sort
       .SetRange Range("O1:O" & SortO)
       .Header = xlYes
       .MatchCase = False
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
   End With
Columns("P:P").Select
```

I added the Row length part since each column I need to sort has a different length.
I need to sort from column O all they way to column CJ.

I'm sure there is an easier way other then writing a block for each column, I am fairly new and looking for a better solution.

In advance any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that did the trick for me.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sort_Many()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, i As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("data")
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    
    For i = 15 To 88
        ws.Columns(i).Sort Key1:=Cells(1, i), order1:=1, Header:=1
        ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```